# In XCode 13.4.1 Bundle Version string from info plist got empty while app building

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist

While building an app, bundle version string got automatically erased. I am using XCode 13.4.1. Screenshots for reference. Why this is happening?

[image: info plist]

Comment: Did you clear the derive data and reopen the project again?

Comment: @AnkurLahiry i already tried may times with derived data clearing. but no any luck